# Invasion of the body snatchers: Backbone view fade in and scale out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I have a backbone view inside a div. I want it to fade in and scale out just like the animation at
http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ (See Fade In and Scale animation)

I want the div (which is 2 pages long) to fade in and scale when the user clicks a button. 
hen when the user clicks the second button (the close button), it should reverse the effect (fade out and scale out) and disappear (display: none).

I have the following CSS. When I click the first button, the fade in and scale works, but when I click the second button, the reverse effect doesn't work.

Can someone take a look?

```
@keyframes fadeInScale {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
        display: block;
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
        display: block;
    }
}


.overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: -$headerHeight;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
}

.fade-scale-in {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}

.fade-scale-out {
    display: none;
    animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 reverse;
}
```

Here's the Jquery:

When the user clicks the button that opens the page (div):

```
this.overlayView.$el.removeClass('fade-scale-out').addClass('fade-scale-in');
this.overlayView.render();
```

And when the user clicks the close button to close the page (div):

```
this.overlayView.$el.removeClass('fade-scale-in').addClass('fade-scale-out');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification to the section that opens the page and and then see if the close page piece works. My guess is that the render is overwriting the fade-scale-in class added to the $el.

```js
this.overlayView.$el.removeClass('fade-scale-out');
this.overlayView.render();
this.overlayView.$el.addClass('fade-scale-in');
```